# LiveObjects load balancing and/or duplication on FIFO

Tags: orange-api

I try to connect LiveObjects and consume data from FIFO using more than one MQTT connection.
The documentation https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual.html#FIFO is not very clear on how the message distribution is broadcasted between the connection.
Is seems that the messages can be load balanced depending the consumer Id which is the MQTT client Id.

What does it means:

- same client Id, load balancing
- different client Id, duplication to all connection

In case of duplication, what leads LiveObjects to remove the message from the FIFO ?

Does-it wait that all the consumer ack the message ?

What appends is one consumer do not ack the message ?

Answer (score 1):

A message stored in a fifo is delivered to the first subscriber available whatever its cliendID. The message is removed from the fifo once the subscriver acknowledges it. If no ack, the message is kept in the fifo and still available for the next susbscriber ready.

Answer (score 0):

To complete, a LiveObjects expert inform me that the FIFO is always load balanced and never duplicated like it could be on the ROUTER.